# Run TestNG test from another class

Tags: selenium, testng

Is there any way to run TestNG test from another java class.

```
@Test
public void f(Integer n, String s) {
}
```

I need to run the same method in a single suite with different arguments.(Inside for loop)

Is it possible?

Also, I see that dataprovider method should return `Object[][]`. This works fine for methods with two arguments. Can we send more than two arguments??

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] dp() {
    return new Object[][] { new Object[] { 1, "a" }, new Object[] { 2, "b" }, };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
public void f(Integer n, String s, char c, double d, String s2) {
}
```

I am trying to do it by using some TestNG classes

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    classes.add(new XmlClass("com.test.PortalTest"));

    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("Portal Test Suite");

    XmlTest test = null;
    for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
        test = new XmlTest();
        test.setName("Portal Test - " + index);
        test.setXmlClasses(classes);
        test.addParameter("downloadFileIndex", String.valueOf(index));
        suite.addTest(test);
    }

    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    suites.add(suite);

    TestListenerAdapter testListenerAdapter = new TestListenerAdapter();

    TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
    Class[] classesClasses = {PortalTest.class};
    testNG.setTestClasses(classesClasses);
    testNG.setXmlSuites(suites);
    testNG.addListener(testListenerAdapter);
    testNG.run();

    System.out.println("Passed : " + testListenerAdapter.getPassedTests());
    System.out.println("Failed : " + testListenerAdapter.getFailedTests());
    System.out.println("Skipped : " + testListenerAdapter.getSkippedTests());

}
```

I use below code to run method having `@Test` for one time. How can i run the `@Test` method multiple times in a same test.

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { PortalTest.class });
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. TestNG test methods are always `public` so you can instantiate an instance of any test class from another test class and simply call the method you want from another test class.
2. TestNG data providers must return either an array of arrays, `Object[][]`, or an iterator of arrays, `Iterator<Object[]>`, so you can certainly use as many (or as few) arguments as you'd like.

e.g.

```java
@DataProvider
public Object[][] dp() {
    return new Object[][] {
            new Object[] { 1, "a", 'x', 3.14, "pi" },
            new Object[] { 2, "b", 'y', 6.28, "tau" },
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
public void f(Integer n, String s, char c, double d, String s2) {
    new OtherTestClass().f(n, s);
}
```

Comment: I need to run it as a test like we do in eclipse. Right click -> Run As -> TestNG test which would run as test and generate report. Can this action be done through java using classes `TestNg`, `Suite`, `Test` and methods like `testNg.run()`....

Comment: is there a way to create `Object[][]` dynamically?

Comment: If you want to run a suite of tests programmatically see http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Comment: You can create a `List<Object>`, add to it your data for each test case, and then convert it to a typed array with `list.stream().toArray(Object[]:new)` but it would be simpler to instead return `list.iterator()` and change your `dp` method's return type to `Iterator<Object[]>`.

Comment: can we pass arguments from another class to test using `TestNG `. I need to add arguments dynamically by using for loop

Comment: Not in the conventional way, no. Do you actually need separate suites though? If not, have you tried TestNG's `Factory` annotation?